# Stochastic processes: understanding a complete filtration

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

My understanding is that the filtration for a stochastic process represents the information known, meaning that at time $t$ I know which sets in $\mathscr{F}_t$ are true or false. A filtration is complete if the sigma algebra for the probability space is complete and $\mathscr{F}_0$ contains all the null sets. Suppose my stochastic process consists of a sequence of normal random variables.  Then the set {(0,0,0,...)}, the event that every variable equals zero, is a null set and is therefore an element of $\mathscr{F}_0$. The same is true for every sequence of real numbers. Since all these sets are in $\mathscr{F}_0$, doesn't this mean that at time 0 I know the whole future of the process, because I know which of these sets are true and which are false? Why is it okay to add this information to the filtration?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi: Think of an event like $max( \{X_t\}) < 0$ where $t = 2$. You don't know that at time $t = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, @markleeds.  If all the sequences of real numbers are in $\mathscr{F}_0$, and I know which one is true, then I know if the maximum of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is less than zero, do I not?  For example, if the one true sequence is {(-1,-2,0,0,...)}, then I know the maximum of the first two values is less than 0.  What's wrong with this thinking? Again, I am assuming that at time 0 I know whether each set in $\mathscr{F}_0$ is true or false.

Comment: I get what you're arguing but the counter argument has something to do with lebesgue theory I think. I can't explain it ( hopefully someone else with more mathematical ability can ) but $F_{0}$ does not contain all the possible sequences. If it did, then there would be no need for an $F_{1}$ say. I understand your point that  all sequences have null measure so they must belong to $F_{0}$ but somehow that's not correct. $F_{0}$ only contains information up to and including time $t=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $\{X(t):t\geqslant 0\}$ a real-valued stochastic process - that is, for each nonnegative $t$, $X(t):\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is $(\mathcal A,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ a measurable function. The natural filtration of $X$ with respect to $\mathcal A$ is $\mathbb F=(\mathcal F_t)_{t\geqslant 0}$ where
$$
\mathcal F_t = \sigma\left\{X_s^{-1}(A) : 0\leqslant s\leqslant t, A\in\mathcal A \right\}.
$$
$\mathbb F$ is a complete filtration if $(\Omega, \mathcal F_t, \mathbb P)$ is a complete measure space for all $t$ - that is, if every $\mathcal F_t$ contains the set of all sets that are contained within a $\mathbb P$-null set,
$$
\mathcal N_{\mathbb P} := \{A\subset\Omega: A\subset B \text{ for some } B\in\mathcal F \text{ with } \mathbb P(B)=0 \}.
$$
This is mostly a technical matter of measure theory that is important when, for example we want to work with processes that are right-continuous. We don't know from the elements of in a given set in the filtration what's "true or false" for a given process - that is more akin to the notion of the sample path $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ for a fixed $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you @Math1000.  Can you please clarify your last sentence?  I thought the sets in the filtration at time $t$ give us information about the process up to time $t$.  In other words, at time $t$ we know whether each set in the filtration at time $t$ is true or false.

Comment: For example, for repeated coin tossing, after toss 1 the filtration contains: (1) $\Omega$ (all sequences of Hs and Ts - always true), (2) $\emptyset$ (always false), (3) the set of all sequences beginning with H, and (4) the set of all sequences beginning with T.  We know which of (3) or (4) is true after the first toss.  However, this filtration is not complete, because all the individual sequences of Hs and Ts are null sets in $\mathcal{A}$, and so must be added to every $\mathcal{F}_t$ to make $\mathbb{F}$ complete.

Comment: But if all the sequences are in $\mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t$, don’t I know which sequences are true and which are not true?  And therefore I know the future of the process beyond time $t$? Or am I incorrect to think of a filtration at time $t$ as representing the information available to me at time $t$, meaning I know which sets in $\mathcal{F}_t$ are true or false at time $t$?

Comment: The sets in the filtration at time $t$ are as defined. The intuition of "information available at time $t$" should only be taken so far. In the case where $\Omega = \{H,T\}^\infty$ is the set of all possible sequences of coin flips, indeed each singleton set consisting of a given sequence is a member of $\mathcal F_0$, but these give no probabilistic information about the actual process. Indeed, each of these sets has probability zero...